# How to set properties at parent definition on run time

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have a dependency where i need to change version value in parent definition from command line . how can i do that

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mobile</groupId>
    <artifactId>aris-project</artifactId>
    <version>${aris.version}</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: You mean something like `mvn clean install -Daris.version=1.2.3` ?

Comment: Anyways is fine but i need to update this value at run time.

Comment: What do you mean by "at runtime"? Do you mean when running Maven or when running the resulting Java program?

Comment: while running maven command.

Comment: So have you tried what I suggested?